# Certificate for Distribution of App in iOS devices

Tags: ios, provisioning

I am trying to upload a binary of an App so that I can test out in app purchase.I can run the Application on intended iOS device which mean the development profile is working fine. But when I try to archive the file I get the error as shown in the image. Since i cannot import the private key associated to the profile show in the error I want to generate my own certificate using keyChain. So I created the certificate but I can't find the option send invite to a distributor or upload a certificate. My profile status is Admin. What should i do.

[image: Error in distribution file]

Comment: You should revoke your distribution certificate in your account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should revoke your distribution certificate in your account.
So that it ask the `.cer` keyfile in your account again. You can create `.cer` file in your keychain go to `Request a Certificate from a Certificate Authority` and give your details that your mail id etc. so that it will create `.cer` file and in developer.apple.com , you can upload the `cer` file once you revoke your distribution certificate so that it will generate the certificate which can be installed in your system.
[image]
[image]